# Formatting a table in R with special symbols in columns

Tags: r

So I have run some analysis in `R` which I store in a `data.frame()` and at the end of the program I want to print a table for the user that is easy to read. I could just return the data frame to the user but I want to have column header names with space or special character (in particular I want there to be a percent sign).  So my thought was that I could use the `print()` or `paste()` function to output a sort of table format.

So at the end of running the code I want the output to look exactly like the following:

```
     X       Y   P/E%
0.66120836 0.379 0.99
0.57320298 0.028 0.50
0.77160759 0.024 0.96
0.01532545 0.565 0.37
0.96046884 0.066 0.77
```

Here is some example code to generate the data I want to output:

```
x = runif(5)
y = round(runif(5),3)
z = round(runif(5),2)
```

Now I could use the `data.frame()` command but it won't allow me a column header like `P/E%`, for example

```
A = data.frame(X=x,Y=y,PE=z)
```

Because it won't like the / or the % sign. The closet thing I could think up to solve the problem is the following:

```
temp = paste("X","Y","P/E% \n",sep=" ")
for(i in 1:5){
    temp = paste(temp,paste(x[i],y[i],z[i],"\n",sep=" "),sep=" ")
}
```

but the spacing is weird if the column headers are long or the number of digits are different.  If I go with the paste option, which I like, is there a way to make it so that the columns are aligned nicely no matter the shape of the data or number of digits?  Like a left or right align?

Lastly, this code is going into an `R` shiny app and so it would be very nice to be able to solve this problem without having to have the user load a package to solve it.

Comment: Since you're putting it in Shiny, you need to check out `renderTable`, which already takes care of this for you (through `xtable`, which you can also use by itself). `knitr::kable` is also useful for formatting tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Column names can have special symbols in them if they are quoted (if you disable validity checking of column names):

```
A = data.frame(X=x, Y=y, 'P/E%'=z, check.names=FALSE)
```

You then need to always use quotes with `$` calls for access. The `$`-function accepts any of the three types of quotes as long as they are matched:

```
a$`P/E%`
```

The "[[" function is designed to handle quoted arguments, but do not use backticks:

```
A[['P/E%']]  # so this is one situation where $ is better than "[["
```

If you have an actual use case in mind, it needs to be presented more completely than just saying "needs to work with Shiny", but as far as packages go both `$` and `[[` are about as "base" as you can get.

Comment: Not on my machine: `A$'P/E%'` returns `[1] 0.95 0.88 0.10 0.19 0.55`

Comment: You're right, sorry! That's only whole objects, I guess, where normal quotes would definitely denote strings.

Comment: In fact using backticks around a column names with "[[" will throw an error.

Comment: And no, I just wanted to make you all aware that it will be in Shiny so I don't want to solve this using packages. The packages part is important i could have said it without mentioning Shiny.