# sort data columns in R with % symbols in it

Tags: r, symbols, columnsorting

I have a small data table with the % symbol in the column names. For brevity I am only showing part of the output.

```
thevars w1.2.5% w1.97.5%    w2.2.5% w2.97.5%    w3.2.5% w3.97.5%    mw.2.5% mw.97.5%
V10     0.043   0.06        0.019   0.023       0.09    0.114       0.054   0.062
V4      0.071   0.094       0.015   0.02        0.05    0.067       0.049   0.056
V5      0.028   0.039       0.072   0.095       0.03    0.044       0.048   0.054
V6      0.021   0.03        0.062   0.087       0.02    0.025       0.037   0.045
V7      0.079   0.103       0.016   0.021       0.071   0.096       0.061   0.068
V8      0.042   0.06        0.06    0.08        0.034   0.05        0.051   0.057
V9      0.016   0.021       0.092   0.121       0.021   0.029       0.045   0.054
```

The code I used in creating the table is as below.

```
data.frame(aggregate(DF[-1], list(DF[[1]]), quantile, probs = c(0.025, 0.975)), check.names=FALSE)
```

I checked the structure of the DF and it shows the following (sample output).

```
 $ thevars: chr  "V10" "V4" "V5" "V6" ...
 $ w1     : num [1:7, 1:2] 0.043 0.071 0.028 0.021 0.079 0.042 0.016 0.06 0.094 0.039 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : NULL
  .. ..$ : chr  "2.5%" "97.5%"
 $ w2     : num [1:7, 1:2] 0.019 0.015 0.072 0.062 0.016 0.06 0.092 0.023 0.02 0.095 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : NULL
  .. ..$ : chr  "2.5%" "97.5%"
 $ w3     : num [1:7, 1:2] 0.09 0.05 0.03 0.02 0.071 0.034 0.021 0.114 0.067 0.044 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : NULL
  .. ..$ : chr  "2.5%" "97.5%"
 $ mw     : num [1:7, 1:2] 0.054 0.049 0.048 0.037 0.061 0.051 0.045 0.062 0.056 0.054 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : NULL
```

What I want do is sort the table based on one of the columns in descending order. I have tried different things, but to not avail.

When I ran the following code, it shows that "w1.2.5%" is not in the column name.

```
"w1.2.5%" %in% colnames(thetable)
[1] FALSE
```

However, when I ran the code below it shows that there is "w1" in the column name.

```
"w1" %in% colnames(thetable)
[1] TRUE
```

My question is how do I sort based on the column header? I have tried everything in the answer on this link([Formatting a table in R with special symbols in columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36002565/formatting-a-table-in-r-with-special-symbols-in-columns)) and it hasn't worked out.

Answer (score 0):

Without providing `DF` I am unable to exactly replicate your dataframe. However, it works for me to include the `%` symbol in a column name:

```
data.frame("w1.2.5%" = 5, check.names = F)
> "w1.2.5%" %in% colnames(df)
[1] TRUE
```

If the `%` symbol is giving you trouble, perhaps you could (1) replace the symbol, (2) conduct your manipulations, and then 3 (3) replace the symbol:

```
colnames(df) <- gsub("%", "perc", colnames(df))
df$w1.2.5perc <- 10
colnames(df) <- gsub("perc", "%", colnames(df))
```